# Run custom programs on all instances within a Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtual, azure-vm-scale-set

There must be something I'm missing, but I've generated a virtual machine scale set from a custom image and I'd like to run a web server .exe on all of them.

Is the only option to manually get into each individual instance and run the code? Do I do that through SSH?

This is all very new to me and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed it through Azure Resource Manager templates, you can use a `CustomScriptExtension` to run a Powershell script like in [this example template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows/azuredeploy.json).

If you already have the .exe on your server and you just want it to run whenever the machine starts, I would [register it as a Windows service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251192) and configure the startup type as `Automatic` before creating the image.